# SSRS Group By Parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, group-by

If I have a report parameter (`@Fruit`) that allows multiple selections how can I use the parameter as a column group in an SSRS Matrix?

Typically, I would use the parameter in my query like the following:

```
WHERE tbl.fruit In ( @Fruit )
```

Then I would use the column in the dataset as my group. However, in this case I need the full dataset returned. I can't filter the query, but I still want to only display the groups selected by the parameter. If my query returns Apples, Oranges and Bananas, but the parameter only selects Apples and Oranges my tablix should only have 2 columns.

I've tried setting the Group By expression to `=Parameters!Fruit.Value`, but then I get this error:

> The Group expression used in grouping ‘ColumnGroup’ returned a data
>   type that is not valid. (rsInvalidExpressionDataType)

My parameter type is **Text** and I've tried it with and without allowing blank values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it seems you want to filter a report object based on the selected values in a multi-value parameter, in the case `@Fruit`?

If, as you say, you can't apply the filter in the Dataset query/stored procedure, you can apply a filter at the tablix level like:

[image]

Where the expression is:

```
=IIf(InStr(Join(Parameters!Fruit.Value, ","), Fields!Fruit.Value)) > 0
  , "INCLUDE"
  , "EXCLUDE")
```

Basically this is using the [JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx) function to get a comma-delimted list of selected values, then checking if the *Fruit* field in the object dataset is in that list; if it is, include it.

Comment: Thanks Ian. That solution works for me. I appreciate your time.