# Grouping tablix by Paramater is SSRS (#Error) and automatically adding (0) when selected in expression

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dashboard

I hope this is not a stupid question, but I have searched everywhere and have tried everything.

I have a dashboard and would like to group the tablix (The dashboard is inside the tablix) by one of the Parameters (Consultant). There are a few Data sets(queries) in the report and all of the Parameters are filtered with `IN` in the `where` clause.

The problem I have is that when I go to the row group properties and select the Parameter in the expression, then it automatically adds a (0) at the end. If I take the (0) away then I get the error message:

> the group expression used in grouping 'Group1' returned a data type
>   that is not valid

I know the (0) is for getting the first value, but I am using Multi-valued Parameters.

I have tried one thing I found, but unfortunately it didn't work for me ([SSRS Group By Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729339/ssrs-group-by-parameter)).

**Edited:**

**This is to show you that there are multiple Data Sets(Queries) in this report**

[image]

I have the dashboard in a tablix so that I can group for each Consultant, so when I choose 3 Consultant, I get 3 dashboards.

**Expression used:**

[image]

**Then I get this error:**

[image]

I have also tried using the CStr, but also no luck.

**When I add the Parameter in any expression box it automatically put the (0) as below:**

[image]

But then it doesn't use the parameter as I get an #Error where is should be the Consultant name.

**I also used this option for page break but end up with graphs below each other:**

[image]

**This is what happens to the Charts(Sub Reports)**

[image]

**To give you an idea how the dashboard should look for each Consultant.**

[image]

Regarding the other question I saw. I just tried exactly as they said but also no luck

I hope this isn't too much information. Just trying to help you help me.

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

**Parameter Properties:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly did you try from the other question? Show us the expression you are trying to use in the group, please.

Comment: It sounds like you need to `JOIN` the parameters, but without seeing what you are actually doing, it's hard to give you an answer.

Comment: I have made the changes to the question. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the list tool to separate the sub reports by Consultant? A list acts like a container and will create whatever is inside for your grouping. You should also be able to apply a parameter to the list for filtering.

Comment: Yes I have tried doing that as well. I've tried list, tablix and matrix. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong somewhere. It sucks because this is the only thing that I cant get to work and to be honest I've been sitting with this for over a week and cant figure it out :( I still don't understand why when I choose the parameter in any expression box then it adds the (0).

Comment: Can you post the properties of the parameter? If the value of the parameter is equivalent to one of the fields, should you be grouping on that field instead? Otherwise, how does the report know how to what data to group together?

Comment: Hi C Bell, sorry for the delay. I have added the Parameter properties as requested. It all makes sense in regards to what you said regarding grouping with the actual field. Problem in that there are different data sets and with I put the whole dashboard in a table, then I can only choose one Data Sets (Hope this makes sense). Sorry if I am being "Stupid". Its a real struggle. Thanks for still trying to help :)

Comment: Okay, I think I understand the issue now. You don't need to group your dashboard by parameter!Consultant.value, you need to group it by field!Consultant.value, then add the filter field!Consultant.value = parameters!Consultant.value to each dataset. Or better yet, add the parameter to the dataset queries using consultant = @Consultant in the where clause.

Comment: Thank you C Bell, I tried as you said. I had the parameters in the query already but using the IN operator in the WHERE clause otherwise I get the error for multi-select. If I use the filter only I also cant use the field!Consultant.value = parameters!Consultant.value in the DataSet filter as I also get the same error. If I use the IN Operator then the dashboard still does the same thing. I have also taken out the parameters out of the query and used the DataSet filter, but also still does the same :( I have never come across something like this. Thank you once again for you help.

Comment: You will need adjust you query a little if you want to allow the users to select more than one value for the parameter. If you are using TSQL (or similar), you'll you need a table valued function to turn the parameter values into their own table, then inner join (or cross apply)  the parameter table the results to filter the dataset.

Comment: Thank you C Bell, I will try do that.

Comment: Hi C Bell. I have created a table valued function that return the Consultant names with CROSS JOIN, but I am still stuck. I am not sure if I should do this in all the data sets that the Dashboard is using or should this only be in the data set that is used for the Parameter? I have tried both but the problem now is that the graphs are still showing underneath each other as in the pics above. Sorry if this sounds stupid I am trying everything I can to get this dashboard to show a dashboard per consultant. Let me know if I must send you any additional infomation as I am not giving up on this :)

Comment: You will need to use the cross apply technique in each dataset where you want to filter the results. Try this first: create just a simple table using the dataset that currently uses the cross apply. Make sure that when you're selecting one consultant from the parameter options, you are only getting that data in your table. If it works, you know you've done it right and you're ready to do the same to the other datasets.

Comment: Thank you I will do that and let you know. I would like to confirm something though. When doing the cross apply...Do I pass the @Parameter eg: CROSS JOIN dbo.Function(@ParameterName) or do I use that actual Column Name in that query. The dashboard's graphs(Sub reports) use different data sets than the mail report. Will this effect anything? Once again thanks for your time :)

Comment: It should look like this:
CROSS APPLY dbo.Function(@ParameterName) PN 
WHERE PN.value = table.consultantname

Comment: If you want the graphs to reflect only the selected consultant, you will have to update those datasets as well.

Comment: Hi C Bell, I have done as you said. I did this with the sub report(Graph) itself to test. When I choose one of the consultants then I get the correct data on the graph (Some progress :)), but when I select more than one then I get the error: <Procedure or Function dbo.TVFConsultant has too many arguments specified>. In the parameter Data Set I use the Distinct Consultant names. Is this why I'm getting this error? Thank you

Comment: If you are going to allow more than one consultant, you will need to add a delimiter to your table value function. Like this: dbo.TVFConsultant(@ParameterName, ',')

Comment: Fantastic! Glad to help. :)